# Why does this PostgreSQL full-text search break on a different (RDS) server?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, full-text-search, amazon-rds

On several development servers, this query has returned expected records:

```
SELECT name, name_tsv FROM vision 
WHERE name_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park');
```

name_tsv was originally populated on my dev server with

```
UPDATE vision SET name_tsv=to_tsvector(name);
```

and is kept up to date with a trigger.

I have created the same database on an AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance. Both dev and RDS postgres versions are at 9.3.1. As far as I can tell, pg_catalog on each has the same FTS Configurations, Dictionaries, Parsers, and Templates (default; I haven't messed with anything in here). I cannot access the pg conf file on the RDS instance, of course. On this RDS instance, the above query returns 0 records.

I ran this diagnostic query on both:

```
SELECT name, 
name_tsv, 
to_tsvector(name), 
plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park'), 
name_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park') AS matches_stored_name,
to_tsvector(name) @@ plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park') AS matches_fresh_tsvector
FROM vision WHERE id_vision = 2977;
```

The result on the RDS instance is:

```
"1609: Washington Square Park";"'1609':1 'park':4 'squar':3 'washington':2";"'1609':1 'park':4 'square':3 'washington':2";"'washington' & 'square' & 'park'";f;t
```

The result on the dev instance is:

```
"1609: Washington Square Park";"'1609':1 'park':4 'squar':3 'washington':2";"'1609':1 'park':4 'squar':3 'washington':2";"'washington' & 'squar' & 'park'";t;t
```

It appears from the above that on RDS, to_tsvector() and plainto_tsquery() both seem not to produce the truncated lexeme 'squar' that they do on the dev server (the same no-lexeme pattern happens with other strings). However, I tried running

```
UPDATE vision SET name_tsv=to_tsvector(name);
```

on the RDS server, but name_tsv did not change (still = "'1609':1 'park':4 'squar':3 'washington':2").

What can I do on the new RDS server to make the first query return expected records the same way it does on my dev server? I think I just need to make plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park') normalize tokens to lexemes (e.g. return 'squar' not 'square'), but I can't tell from [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/textsearch-controls.html) how to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT name, name_tsv FROM vision 
WHERE name_tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park');
```

uses the *default dictionary*. I'd say the default dictionary is different between the two machines. See:

```
regress=> SELECT plainto_tsquery('Washington Square Park');
         plainto_tsquery         
---------------------------------
 'washington' & 'squar' & 'park'
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT plainto_tsquery('english', 'Washington Square Park');
         plainto_tsquery         
---------------------------------
 'washington' & 'squar' & 'park'
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT plainto_tsquery('simple', 'Washington Square Park');
         plainto_tsquery          
----------------------------------
 'washington' & 'square' & 'park'
(1 row)
```

Compare the result of running:

```
SHOW default_text_search_config ;
```

on both machines. Betcha they're different.

Comment: Bingo. So the answer is, specify the dictionary returned by SHOW default_text_search_config; on the dev machine as the first argument to plainto_tsquery(). I find the documentation to plainto_tsquery() unclear about this; if you have a good reference, please share.

Comment: @Kim No better reference at hand. I agree that the docs could be clearer. A patch would be greatly appreciated ;-)